# Vert.x HttpClient::handler is deprecated- Then what should I use?

Tags: java, vert.x

I am using the vertx http client to make requests.

```
httpClient.post(requestOptions).handler((httpResponse) -> {
                        countDownLatch.countDown();
                    })
                    .exceptionHandler((exception) -> {
                        logger.debug(exception);
                    })
                    .write(payloadBuffer).end();
```

I'm trying to make many requests in parallel, using the handler to catch the response and decrement a CountDownLatch.

But the handler method is deprecated

[image]

I've looked around. But I just can't figure out what I'm supped to use in it's place. I figure it's right under my nose, but i'm not seeing it.

How do I handle httpClient responses without the handler method?

Comment: If you're using Vert.x 3, do nothing. If you're using Vert.x 4, change the parameter from `Handler<HttpClientResponse> handler` to `Handler<AsyncResult<HttpClientResponse>>`, as [**documented**](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpClientRequest.html#handler-io.vertx.core.Handler-): *Deprecated. this method will break in Vert.x 4, the handler will use an `Handler<AsyncResult<HttpClientResponse>>`*

Comment: Ah. I'm very early into development. Should I make the switch to 4? Are there significant performance improvements?

Comment: Go to their site (https://vertx.io/), and you'll see that the current version is 3.8.